# Spawn command not found

Tags: shell, expect

I trying to use the spawn command to connect to remote server, execute some commands/script.

Here is script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
for i in `srvctl status database -d PROD | awk -F " " '{print $(NF)}'`
do
echo "value of i is $i"
spawn ssh "$i"
echo "vijay"
done
```

Here is output

```
bash-3.2$ sh a.sh
value of i is prod1
a.sh: line 8: spawn: command not found
vijay
value of i is prod2
a.sh: line 8: spawn: command not found
vijay
```

I am using RHEL 5.11 .

```
 bash-3.2$ expect -v
 expect version 5.43.0
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: public-key ssh authentication is a lot safer and a lot more reliable than a scripted login with expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a script as an argument to shell, like you are doing:

```
sh a.sh
```

the shebang will be ignored and the script `a.sh` will be interpreted by `sh`. As there is no such command as `spawn` in your system (`spawn` is `expect` specific command), shell is throwing the given error.

Given your shebang is `#!/usr/bin/expect`, it is not clear what you are trying to do as you have many (all except `spawn`) non `expect` specific commands in the script.

Comment: After referring to few old posts, i have written those commands, If its wrong, then how I can run ssh to remote server and run some commands  ?

Comment: @Vijay That goes as a new question i am afraid :)

Comment: Posted as new question.